# Is there any online reference to Spherical Model and the Infinite Spin Dimensionality Limit?

Tags: specific-reference

It is cited a lot in the literature but I haven't been able to find any electronic account of it

M. Kac and C. J. Thompson, Spherical Model and the Infinite Spin Dimensionality Limit, Physica Norvegica 5 163-168 (1971)

Thanks!